# Error :Overrides method in org.springframework.boot.CommandlineRunner

Tags: java, spring

I visit [spring.io](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)
to develop my first spring application but after i do all instruction , I face  with this error "Error:java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" .

If  you have any idea , please help me

Thank you

[Picture of class has error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiICd.png)

Comment: i Have question for people give negetive vote ! why you dont answer !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a warning, but an indication and allows navigation to the super method using the mouse. The icon(s) can be disabled in File | Settings | Editor | General | Gutter Icons.
and in my case , my issue solve by change java version to 8 .